# How do I return a TreeSet of the values contained in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, treemap, treeset

I am trying to get a set of all the values for keys in a TreeMap that are greater than some value, key.

Code attempt below:

```
TreeSet<E> set = (TreeSet<E>)tMap.tailMap(key, false).values();
```

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`values()` returns a `Collection`, so you can always feed that `Collection` to `TreeSet` constructor (assuming your `E` class implements `Comparable<E>`):

```
TreeSet<E> set = new TreeSet<E>(tMap.tailMap(key, false).values());
```

If you wish the `TreeSet` to use some custom `Comparator` instead of natural ordering, you can write:

```
TreeSet<E> set = new TreeSet<E> (yourComparator);
set.addAll(tMap.tailMap(key, false).values());
```